# Como comparar se o valor de uma coluna do dataframe esteja em um array se estiver criar uma nova coluna com esse valor?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
lista = array(['NF', 'BT', 'C', 'N', 'I', 'IP',
       'Aa', 'Sa', 'Gl', 'Et', 'To', 'Hr',
       'Cr', 'Ro', 'X', 'Oa', 'Ml', 'Me'], dtype=object)

"DATAFRAME" 
  x_1 x_2
0  NF  0
1  A   0 
2  B   0 
3  KK  0 
4  Gl  0
5  Oa  0
```

A saida desejada seria essa abaixo :

```
  x_1 x_2
0  NF  NF
1  A   0 
2  B   0 
3  KK  0 
4  Gl  Gl
5  Oa  Oa
```

Se o valor da coluna for igual à qualquer um dado do array ele retornar a coluna nova com esse valor caso contrario retorne 0

Comment: Desculpe não entendi como chegou da lista ao dataframe? Ou seria comparar lista com uma coluna dum dataframe cujo o código não está presente na pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi correto, use o `isin()`

### Criando lista e dataframe para teste

```
>>> lista = array(['NF', 'BT', 'C', 'N', 'I', 'IP',
...        'Aa', 'Sa', 'Gl', 'Et', 'To', 'Hr',
...        'Cr', 'Ro', 'X', 'Oa', 'Ml', 'Me'], dtype=object)

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"x_1": ["NF", "A", "B", "KK", "Gl", "Oa"]})
```

### Criando nova coluna

```
>>> df["x_2"] = df[df["x_1"].isin(lista)]

>>> df
  x_1  x_2
0  NF   NF
1   A  NaN
2   B  NaN
3  KK  NaN
4  Gl   Gl
5  Oa   Oa
```

### Preenchendo NaN com 0 (zero)

```
>>> df["x_2"].fillna(0, inplace=True)

>>> df
  x_1 x_2
0  NF  NF
1   A   0
2   B   0
3  KK   0
4  Gl  Gl
5  Oa  Oa
```